# setVelocity doesn't change on OutofScreen

Tags: java, android, box2d, andengine

I have just started learning about AndEngine, and was following a tutorial on making the Sprite move, thought i'd figure out if i wanted to reverse it after it went out of the screen,i'd do this.

```
@Override
public void move() {
    this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityX(-100);

    this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityY(100);
    OutOfScreenX();
    OutOfScreenY();

    }


// ===========================================================
// Methods
// ===========================================================
private void OutOfScreenX() {
    if (mX > MainActivity.CAMERA_WIDTH) { // OutOfScreenX (right)
        mX = 0;
    } else if (mX < 0) { // OutOfScreenX (left)
        mX = MainActivity.CAMERA_WIDTH;
    }
}

private void OutOfScreenY() {
    if (mY > MainActivity.CAMERA_HEIGHT) { // OutOfScreenX (right)
        this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityY(-1000);
        Log.d("Changing Direction","Changed");
    } else if (mY < 0) { // OutOfScreenX (left)
        mY = MainActivity.CAMERA_HEIGHT;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, all this does is making the Sprite bounce at the bottom of the screen. Is there any reason to fix this and how? I understand that another way of doing this is to reverse the Velocity by multiplying it by negative one, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction!

Thanks!

Comment: this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityY(-1000);
Why it is set to -1000?

Comment: Shouldnt that be -100?

Comment: Doesn't matter what you set it to the result is the same. I put 1000 to test if it would make a bigger jump but it didn't either.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are calling the move()-method steadily.

When you do so, the y-velocity is set to 100, then the OutOfScreenY-method is called to check the position of the sprite. In this method the y-velocity is set to -1000, so the sprite is moving the opposite direction.

But the move()-methos is called again, setting the velocity back to 100. Then again, the OutOfScreenY-methos is called an changes the velocity to -1000.

The velocity is changing steadily between 100 and -1000 what would explain the bouncing.